# Flutter app is crashing on iOS 17 or more with Google Sign In package

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, google-signin

While using `googleSignIn.signIn()` method on my production scheme of iOS the app crashes. This started to happen after I had updated to Xcode 15 and this crash happens only on iOS 17.

It works on stage scheme but does not work on production scheme.

Exception log:

```
flutter: The following PlatformException was thrown Main :: PlatformDispatcher:
flutter: PlatformException(google_sign_in, UIViewController is missing its initial trait collection populated
flutter: during initialization. This is a serious bug, likely caused by accessing properties or methods on
flutter: the view controller before calling a UIViewController initializer. View controller:
flutter: <SFAuthenticationViewController: 0x7fdd551c6a00>, NSInternalInconsistencyException, null)
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      GoogleSignInApi.signIn (package:google_sign_in_ios/src/messages.g.dart:237:7)
flutter: <asynchronous suspension>
flutter: #1      GoogleSignInIOS._signInUserDataFromChannelData (package:google_sign_in_ios/google_sign_in_ios.dart:99:3)
flutter: <asynchronous suspension>
flutter: #2      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:278:30)
flutter: <asynchronous suspension>
```

flutter doctor log:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on macOS 14.2.1 23C71 darwin-arm64, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.16.5 on channel stable at /Users/urvesh/Work/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 78666c8dc5 (12 days ago), 2023-12-19 16:14:14 -0800
    • Engine revision 3f3e560236
    • Dart version 3.2.3
    • DevTools version 2.28.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/urvesh/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15C65
    • CocoaPods version 1.14.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.80.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 15 Pro Max (mobile) • 4D4630D7-AE9D-4246-833B-DCC1D6D3A17B • ios •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-2 (simulator)

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

I tried update google_sign_in package which required flutter upgrade but that too did not work so downgrade back to old flutter version 3.13.9.

Checked GoogleService-Info.plist for both prod & stage but all of the variable/key-value are correct